# String representation of matplotlib figure for doctests

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing doctests for my code that generates some matplotlib figure, I was wondering if there is a way to print the figure in a string representation -- something that displays elements in the figure (lines, points, etc). For example, something like the following:

```
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3], label="line 1")
>>> plt.plot([3,2,1], label="line 2")
>>> fig = plt.gcf()
>>> print fig
<Figure>
    <Line label='line 1'>
    <Line label='line 2'>
```

Comment: Excellent Question - I was wondering the same thing (testing bigger matplotlib creation things is a PAIN). As a workaround: save the figure as a svg, which is basically a test markup

Comment: Printing the svg may be a little too verbose, I just need something simple to show the various plot elements within the figure, along with their labels.